# Changing constraints in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, constraints

I set the top constraint of a container using this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant: 0.00]setActive:true];
```

But then I want to change those constraints when a button appears, here's that function

```
-(void)didConnect{
    [[self connectToKestrelButton] setHidden:NO];
    [[self cancelButton] setHidden:YES];
    [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant: 60.00]setActive:true];
}
```

but when this function is called the constraints update

```
-(void)didDisconnect{
    [[self connectToKestrelButton] setHidden:YES];
    [[self cancelButton] setHidden:YES];
    [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant: 0.00]setActive:true];
}
```

The problem is the container top constraint isn't changing when that function is called, what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you creating `_container` and both buttons via code? Or have you laid them out (and given them constraints) in IB / Storyboard?

Comment: I've given them constraints in story board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have create `_container` in Storyboard and given it constraints, then your code is adding ***additional*** constraints (and I expect you're getting warning / error messages in debug console).

Instead, create an `IBOutlet` connection to the `_container`'s top constraint from Storyboard, such as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *containerTopConstraint;
```

Then, in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
_containerTopConstraint.constant = 0.0;
```

and, when you want to change it, just change the constant:

```
-(void)didConnect{
    [[self connectToKestrelButton] setHidden:NO];
    [[self cancelButton] setHidden:YES];
    _containerTopConstraint.constant = 60.0;
}

-(void)didDisconnect{
    [[self connectToKestrelButton] setHidden:YES];
    [[self cancelButton] setHidden:YES];
    _containerTopConstraint.constant = 0.0;
}
```